# Create DSL connection using Bash Script and connect using the same

Tags: bash, dsl

I have been using ubuntu live OS everyday as my internal hard drive has gone for replacement. On every boot up i need to create a DSL connection to connect to the internet which is a mundane task.
I need to write a bash script for the same.

Comment: Just to verify: do you use pppoeconf to create the dsl connection or some other utility?

Comment: I use network connections(from top right corner)->Edit Connection ->DSL->Add

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store any script that you create. Storing it on a flash drive would be easiest to store it on.

But if your going to use a flash disk, you could just use a 4 gig (minimum) or greater USB flash disk to install Ubuntu on it pretty much the same as if you were installing it Ubuntu to the hard drive. That way every custom setting or additional installed software will remain the same after reboots.

1. Boot Live CD
2. Select  "Install"
3. When presented with a number of options for installing, you should select the option 'Something Else' to bring up the partitioning menu.
4. Select the fist USB drive partition or create it if necessary. For the sake of argument, lets say it is (sdb1), then select it and change the partition type to ext4.
5. Also, set the mount point to "/", and click ok.
6. Select sdb as the partition to install to.
7. Lastly the boot loader must be set to your flash drive (sdb)
8. After completing the install and booting your flash drive, its a good time to connect to your ISP. If your using adslppp  then you should follow these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

After establishing your connection then in a terminal it would be good to run "sudo apt-get update" ; then run "sudo apt-get upgrade". Remember all changes and upgrades will remain.

Comment: My question is "what commands to write in that bash scrip?"